# Bloquear acceso usando login con ajax en el cliente y php en el servidor

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

estoy haciendo una app en Javascript y necesito bloquear el acceso a usuarios no loggeados, en php es sencillo usando $_SESSION  pero con JS no encuentro manera

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Creo que no es posible ya que Javascript es del lado del cliente mientras que las sesiones funcionan en el lado del servidor (por lo que tengo entendido). Por lo tanto, desde Javascript o Ajax tendrás que llamar a algun fichero PHP.

Comment: No es recomendable pero esto te puede servir: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22257502/2097224

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pretendes es hacer control ACL a un recurso expuesto por un backend (php en tu caso), tu frontend esta en Javascript por lo que asumo que estas tratando de acceder a un servicio WEB o REST atraves de una llamada Ajax, este problema no es de la plataforma ni lenguaje que usas sino del protocolo de comunicacion, HTTP es un protocolo sin estado, el objeto session de php puede utilizar cookies en el navegador o un archivo plano en el servidor para persistir el estado de la aplicación mientras navegas en las distintas paginas, necesito mas detalles de que framework utilizas, que libreria usas en el cliente y si la solicitud que haces desde el cliente es a la misma URL o si estas haciendo una solicitud de dominio cruzado, sin eso no puedo darte una respuesta mas concreta pero te dejare unas recomendaciones.

1. Verifica que la dirección de la URL del navegador sea la misma que la del endpoint al cual estas haciendo la llamada Ajax, la razón es porque el navegador no permite enviar la cookie a un servidor si la dirección del endpoint no coincide con la del navegador (esta es una solicitud de dominio cruzado). si esto es así entonces coloca un servicio proxy en el dominio original el mismo que hara a su vez la llamada al servidor destino extrayendo la cookie y enviándola en la petición.
2. Si tu escenario es mas complejo y necesitas varios clientes acceder a tu servidor y hacer un control ACL mas completo entonces considera utilizar uno de los siguientes esquemas de seguridad.

   - Tokens
   - OAuth 2
   - Headers personalizados HTTP

Sobre la seguridad hay una confusión en las anteriores respuestas que te dieron, el control ACL y el esquema de seguridad mencionado, son la implementación de la seguridad en la capa de aplicación (Node, PHP, Java cualquier plataforma), mientras que para proteger la información de ataques como Man-in-the-middle (un intermediario robe tu session) debes asegurar el medio de transporte, en este caso asegura el protocolo HTTP utilizando SSL, HTTP over SSL o mas comúnmente conocido como HTTPS.

En conclusión escoge un esquema de autenticación, el de tokens es el mas sencillo y encontraras librerías que hagan el trabajo por ti en cualquier plataforma pero no olvides cifrar la comunicación utilizando HTTPS.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.